# How to Loop through mulitple MySQL columns and return result in single row?

Tags: php, mysql, function, subquery

I'm using MySQL to go through a query to display the games in which a team has recorded two or more DDs.

The results look like this:

[image]

My issue is that I can only get one player to appear in the Players column when (as I said, two or more players have a DD).

Here is my code:

```
  SELECT * FROM 

        (SELECT game_Date, 
        game_GameID,
        game_SeasonID,
        game_TeamCode,
        teams_Name,
                    ........ other PTS/AST/REB stats too!
        stats1_GameID,
        Sum(stats1_DD) AS 'TotGameDD'

        FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
        ON 
        teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
        AND
        game_GameID = stats1_GameID
    AND
    game_PlayerID = player_PlayerID

        GROUP BY game_GameID
        HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
        ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc) t

    FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
    ON 
    teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
    AND
    game_GameID = stats1_GameID


    GROUP BY game_GameID, stats1_DD
    HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
    ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc





  FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
    ON 
    teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
    AND
    game_GameID = stats1_GameID


    GROUP BY game_GameID, stats1_DD
    HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
    ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc
```

This is where I'm stuck.  I've got stuck in this type of issue in the past too.  I think I need a loop that will go through all the players with a DD, and then return the players name, plus their PTS / AST, and TOTREB stats.

I just can't seem to muster the ability to get it going.

Any help, or direction, is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By DD I assume you mean double-double.

You could try using group_concat which will give you a comma separated list of values for a column:
http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/examples/group_concat.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking into it now.  Sorry, DD = Double Double.  :)

Comment: WOW!! Thanks.  It works.  You have no idea how long I have tried to figure this work.  You are a Godsend!  Is there anyway instead of a comma, to have a line break instead? Again.  Amazing!!

Comment: Looking into how to put more than one column in this now.  Say First Name, Last Name, and then the stats.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help :). From the tag on your question it looks like your sql is embedded in php. In your php you could do a string replace and replace the commas with '\n' (newline).

Comment: If I return two columns in this manner (say F and L name), it returns all three First Names and then All Three Last Names.  Any idea how to get it to display full name?  Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest starting a new thread with all the details of the new problem - then it will be visible to more people who can potentially help.